# closing a non blocking socket channel

Tags: java, sockets, nio, nonblocking

I want to close Java non blocking socket channel after writing a string `byebye`. However, methods in non blocking mode are returned immediately, so calling `close()` may cause the undergoing writing operation to throw a `ClosedChannelException`.

I can think of 2 workarounds:

1. Pop a thread and wait a few milliseconds before closing.
2. Switch to blocking mode before closing, but [Java doc says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html)

> "A channel must be placed into non-blocking mode before being registered with a selector, and may not be returned to blocking mode until it has been deregistered" 
>   
>   Anyway, I feel both ways are dirty. Is there an elegant way to deal with this issue?

Code:

```
String msg = "byebye";
channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.getBytes()));
channel.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

> calling close() may cause the undergoing writing operation to throw a
>   ClosedChannelException.

No it won't. That exception is thrown *by the write() method*. Once the write() method has exited it can't be thrown. The data remains in the kernel's socket output buffer for writing.